# подключение базы access к pascal

Tags: база-данных, pascal, lazarus

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не как подключение к базе через from среда lazarus
побывал
не как выдает ошибки и не добавляет данные в базу
генерирует исключение

```
procedure TForm3.ODBCConnection1AfterConnect(Sender: TObject); begin ODBCConnection1 := ODBCConnection1.Create(nil); ODBCConnection1.Connected:=true; ODBCConnection1.DatabaseName:='C:\Users\ПК\Desktop\проект\.db'; ODBCConnection1.UserName:='admin'; ODBCConnection1.Password:=''; ODBCConnection1.Connected:=true; ODBCConnection1 := ODBCConnection1.Create(nil); – rod rold 2 минуты назад   Править   Удалить
procedure TForm3.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField); begin ODBCConnection1.Connected:=true; //ODBCConnection1.Connected = new(nil); ODBCConnection1.DatabaseName:='C:\Users\ПК\Desktop\проект\Microsoft Access ACCDE Database (.accde).db'; ODBCConnection1 := ODBCConnection1.Create(nil); ODBCConnection1.Create(nil); end; 
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, dbf, DB, odbcconn, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls;

    ODBCConnection1: TODBCConnection;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
    procedure ODBCConnection1AfterConnect(Sender: TObject);
```

Comment: Код в вопрос нужно добавлять текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: procedure TForm3.ODBCConnection1AfterConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ODBCConnection1 := ODBCConnection1.Create(nil);
ODBCConnection1.Connected:=true;
ODBCConnection1.DatabaseName:='C:\Users\ПК\Desktop\проект\.db';
  ODBCConnection1.UserName:='admin';
  ODBCConnection1.Password:='';
  ODBCConnection1.Connected:=true;
 ODBCConnection1 := ODBCConnection1.Create(nil);

Comment: procedure TForm3.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
  ODBCConnection1.Connected:=true;
 //ODBCConnection1.Connected = new(nil);
 ODBCConnection1.DatabaseName:='C:\Users\ПК\Desktop\проект\Microsoft Access ACCDE Database (.accde).db';
 ODBCConnection1 := ODBCConnection1.Create(nil);
 ODBCConnection1.Create(nil);
end;

Comment: Код вставьте в сам вопрос, а не в комментарии. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос нажмите "править" под ним.

Comment: исправьте пожалуйста

Comment: Просто вставьте код в вопрос как есть (только копируйте не из комментариев, а из IDE), поставьте на строке выше и на строке ниже кода три косых апострофа ``` . Не вижу смысла пытаться исправить то что у вас в вопросе сейчас.

Comment: это весь из ide может лучше сам файл pascal загрузить?

Comment: с чего начать исправлять?

Comment: Добавить в вопрос тот код, который относится к проблеме.

Comment: Посмотрите справку, как вставлять код: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code Проще всего делать выделения косыми апострофами (как я уже писал) или тильдами

Comment: Этот код весь проблемный

Comment: давайте без этого , просто поможете и все

Comment: Я оформил для вас как код то, что вы скопировали из комментариев и вставили в вопрос. Вам нужно просто из IDE вставить код в вопрос, и оформить аналогично (просто вставить между строками с тремя косыми апострофами). "Без этого" не получится. После того как вы нормально оформите вопрос, возможно кто-то придет и поможет вам с вашей проблемой.

Comment: спасибо, этого достаточно для кода, теперь жду помощи